# Changing submit by enter to submit by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

hi everyone i have a problem with changing my js code from submitting a textarea form by enter to submitting by click (on click)
here is my code :

```
   /**
 * Allow Comment form to be submitted when the user
 * presses the "enter" key.
 */
$( document ).on('keypress', '#default_add_comment_form textarea, #default_add_comment_form input', function( event ){
    if ( event.keyCode == '13' ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#default_add_comment_form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your post to provide more details. You say you want to submit by click, but click on *what*? What code have you tried to achieve that goal? What problem(s) are you having? Please read Stack Overflow's [guide to asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: hi , i am new to js and i wanted a simple submit button that do the thing! and will appreciate that give me the code i wanted with a simple button code! Thanks

Comment: You don't need any JavaScript for a simple submit button. Just put a `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` element directly in your form and it will work automatically.

Comment: ok but i cant do it right! can u please insert this button in the code that answered to me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By jQuery documentation:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); // call your submit method here
});
```

plus if you want to submit by click or by enter - additionally:

```
if ( event.keyCode == '13' ) {
    event.preventDefault(); // call your submit method here
    $('#default_add_comment_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: can anyone give me this code with having a simple submit button?